# MySQL Order by Optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, indexing

Below is the structure of a table:-

Article: ID, Title, Desc, PublishedDateTime, ViewsCount, Published

Primary Key: ID

Query Used:

```
Select Title FROM Article ORDER By ViewsCount DESC, PublishedDateTime ASC
```

As you can see that I am mixing ASC and DESC & according to MySQL Order By optimization, indexes will not be used.

I have thought to use a composite index using the ViewsCount and PublishedDateTime. Do you recommend to use 2 different keys instead of using composite index. But then I have read that composite index is better than using 2 different keys (if both fields are going to be used).

**Some more information shared:**

The table contains more than 550K+ records and also I am having big trouble in adding and deleting indexes for test purpose. What do you guys recommend ? Should I test on a small sample ?

Below are some more insights:

**Indexes Used:**
1) ViewsCount
2) PublishedDateTime.
3) ViewsCount & PublishedDateTime (named as ViewsDate_Index )

**A) EXPLAIN Query mixing ASC and DESC:**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT title FROM  `article` ORDER BY ViewsCount DESC , PublishedDateTime ASC  LIMIT 0 , 20    

====+===============+=========+======+===============+=====+=========+======+========+================+
id  | select_type   | table   | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra
1   | SIMPLE        | article | ALL  | NULL          | NULL| NULL    | NULL | 550116 |  Using filesort
====+===============+=========+======+===============+=====+=========+======+========+================+
```

**B) EXPLAIN Query using the same sorting order:**

```
EXPLAIN SELECT title FROM  `article` ORDER BY ViewsCount DESC , PublishedDateTime DESC  LIMIT 0 , 20

====+===============+=========+=======+===============+=================+=========+=============+========+================+
id  | select_type   | table   | type  | possible_keys | key             | key_len | ref         | rows   | Extra
1   | SIMPLE        | article | index | NULL          | ViewsDate_Index | 16      | NULL        | 550116 |  
====+===============+=========+=======+===============+=================+=========+=============+========+================+
```

You can see that if ViewsCount and PublishedDateTime are in 2 same sorting order then it uses the ViewsDate_Index index. One thing that I found strange was that possible_keys is NULL and still it selects an index. Can someone explain the reason for this.

*Also any tips on adding indexes on this table because it takes alot of time to add a new index. Any workaround or help in this regarding will be appreciated.*

Comment: Do you have a performance test-case? If not, you do not have a performance problem and anything else is "premature". If so, then you can try things and run performance profiles to determine which works best for you.

Comment: similar issuer there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599301/mysql-compound-index-not-being-used

Comment: @pst: I have modified the post and have shared some more details.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, run the whole query live, and see how it performs. When you've got some benchmarks down, plug the query into your MySQL console and prepend `EXPLAIN` to it. MySQL will not perform the query, but it will display it's plan to execute the query, including where it thinks is important to optimize, which indexes it will use, how many rows it has to traverse, and how efficiently it will traverse each set of rows, among other things as well. The best way to gauge a performance problem is through benchmarking. Use it often.

Comment: How do I know that where MySQL thinks its important to optimize.

Comment: Because MySQL knows a lot more about your data that you do. Plug in your query, prepend EXPLAIN to it, and look at the results. MySQL will tell you exactly what it has to do to get the result you want. Use those results to place your indexes.

Comment: I have given more insights using EXPLAIN. Can you please have a look and answer few things mentioned at the end of post.

Comment: Also do you have any tips or workaround for adding indexes in a table that has a large amount of data. This is actually hindering different tests that I can do before finding the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

In practice, indexes won't be used even for `ORDER By ViewsCount, PublishedDateTime` here, since you SELECT all columns and apply no condition. Is it a real query? Because any conditions will spoil your optimizations.

If your table is so small that you are going to pull it as the whole, indexes will only slow down your query. (Relates to the original query: `SELECT * FROM article ORDER BY ViewsCount DESC, PublishedDateTime;`)

**UPD**

In case where you have 500K+ rows, I think you are going to use `LIMIT` clause. I would do the following:

1. add an index on (ViewCount, PublishedDateTime)
2. rewrite the query as follows:

   ```
   SELECT Title
   FROM (
       SELECT id
       FROM article
       ORDER BY ViewsCount DESC, PublishedDateTime
       LIMIT 100, 100
   ) ids
   JOIN article
   USING (id);
   ```

The ordering would benefit from operating on a subset of data from the covering index. The join will just obtain Titles by ids.

**UPD2**

Another query that might work much better when the cardinality of the ViewCount is rather small (though you should benchmark):

```
SELECT Title
FROM (
  SELECT ViewCount
  FROM article
  GROUP BY ViewCount DESC) as groups
JOIN article USING (ViewCount)
LIMIT 0, 100;
```

It as well assumes you have (ViewCount, PublishedDateTime) index on the table.

Comment: I have mentioned more detail. Can you please help now.

Comment: Thanks. But that didn't help much. I hope you have reviewed the complete information I have shared. I am just confused because you are assuming I will be assuming LIMIT. While if you can see the queries I have shared then you can see that I have used LIMIT in them.

Comment: Also please let me know if you want me to share the Explain results.

Comment: @ConcealedIdentity, if you have set the index, I know the execution plan. But I do not understand now, how you measure if anything helped much or did not help much.

Comment: Because the my current query and your proposed query take around same amount of time to execute.

Answer (score 0):

```
ORDER By ViewsCount DESC, PublishedDateTime ASC
```

is handled effeciently by MySQL 8.0 *if* you have

```
INDEX(ViewsCount DESC, PublishedDateTime ASC)
```

8.0 is when MySQL started honoring the ASC/DESC in INDEX specifications.